# Getting a list of files in the Resources folder - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, resources

Let's say I have a folder in my "Resources" folder of my iPhone application called "Documents".

Is there a way that I can get an array or some type of list of all the files included in that folder at run time?

So, in code, it would look like:

```
NSMutableArray *myFiles = [...get a list of files in Resources/Documents...];
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You can get the path to the `Resources` directory like this,

```
NSString * resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
```

Then append the `Documents` to the path,

```
NSString * documentsPath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
```

Then you can use any of the directory listing APIs of `NSFileManager`.

```
NSError * error;
NSArray * directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsPath error:&error];
```

**Note** : When adding source folder into the bundle make sure you select "Create folder references for any added folders option when copying"

Comment: interesting. without the appending it worked and found everything (including the Documents folder). but with that append, the "directoryOfContents" array is null

Comment: oh wait, "Documents" is a "Group" not a folder. hm. how do I add a folder in my resources folder?

Comment: You can `Drag & Drop` a folder onto the project and the contents will be copied over. **Or** Add a `Copy Files` build phase and specify the directory to copy in it.

Comment: okay, I dragged it in. but it still thinks the directory is empty. hm.

Comment: Did you select `Create folder references for any added folders` option when copying?

Comment: The default option is to create groups for folders. So you should change that or use the second approach I suggested by adding a build phase.

Comment: Cool. :) If you've copied the files over you can use the second approach too.

Answer (score 39):

## Swift

*Updated for Swift 3*

```
let docsPath = Bundle.main.resourcePath! + "/Resources"
let fileManager = FileManager.default

do {
    let docsArray = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: docsPath)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

**Further reading:**

- [NSFileManager class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html)
- [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html)
- [Error Handling docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html)
- [Error Handling in Swift 2.0 blog post](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/error-handling-in-swift-2/)
- [How to find the kind of errors a method may throw and catch them in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977738/how-to-find-the-kind-of-errors-a-method-may-throw-and-catch-them-in-swift)

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The folder “Resources” doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A367E139-1845-4FD6-9D7F-FCC7A64F0408/Robomed.app/Resources, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Folder
), NSUnderlyingError=0x1c4450140 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Comment: I just removed + "/Resources" and got something. I'm not sure what to do with the values in the array I got back.

Comment: Dear readers, I'm not currently updating my iOS answers. It appears this is one of them that could use some updating, though. If you solve the problems written in the comments above, feel free to edit my answer and correct it.

Answer (score 18):

You can try this code also:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSError * error;
NSArray * directoryContents =  [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                      contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:&error];

NSLog(@"directoryContents ====== %@",directoryContents);
```

Comment: you're allocating an array in directoryContents that is immediately overwritten by an array returns by contentsOfDir...

Comment: What I meant to show was just an array that would hold the contents of the directory. The array is there just for example's sake. I've edited it slightly.

Answer (score 18):

Swift version:

```
    if let files = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: Bundle.main.bundlePath ){
        for file in files {
            print(file)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Listing All Files In A Directory

```
     NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
     NSURL *bundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];
     NSArray *contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:bundleURL
                           includingPropertiesForKeys:@[]
                                              options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                                                error:nil];

     NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pathExtension ENDSWITH '.png'"];
     for (NSString *path in [contents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]) {
        // Enumerate each .png file in directory
     }
```

Recursively Enumerating Files In A Directory

```
      NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
      NSURL *bundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL];
      NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [fileManager enumeratorAtURL:bundleURL
                                   includingPropertiesForKeys:@[NSURLNameKey, NSURLIsDirectoryKey]
                                                     options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles
                                                errorHandler:^BOOL(NSURL *url, NSError *error)
      {
         NSLog(@"[Error] %@ (%@)", error, url);
      }];

      NSMutableArray *mutableFileURLs = [NSMutableArray array];
      for (NSURL *fileURL in enumerator) {
      NSString *filename;
      [fileURL getResourceValue:&filename forKey:NSURLNameKey error:nil];

      NSNumber *isDirectory;
      [fileURL getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:nil];

       // Skip directories with '_' prefix, for example
      if ([filename hasPrefix:@"_"] && [isDirectory boolValue]) {
         [enumerator skipDescendants];
         continue;
       }

      if (![isDirectory boolValue]) {
          [mutableFileURLs addObject:fileURL];
       }
     }
```

For more about NSFileManager its [here](http://nshipster.com/nsfilemanager/)

Comment: It will not work if the extenison has the '.'. In other word, this will work: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pathExtension ENDSWITH 'png'"];

Answer (score 6):

### Swift 4:

If you have to do with subdirs **"Relative to project"** (blue folders) you could write:

```
func getAllPListFrom(_ subdir:String)->[URL]? {
    guard let fURL = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "plist", subdirectory: subdir) else { return nil }
    return fURL
}
```

**Usage**:

```
if let myURLs = getAllPListFrom("myPrivateFolder/Lists") {
   // your code..
}
```

Comment: Exaclty what i was looking for. Thanks !!

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3** (and returning URLs)

```
let url = Bundle.main.resourceURL!
    do {
        let urls = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys:[], options: FileManager.DirectoryEnumerationOptions.skipsHiddenFiles)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```