# load all files from a specific atlas Sprite-kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, atlas

Is there a way to load all files from a specific atlas considering that all files names in this atlas are all different ?.

I try the method found on this post 
[Getting a list of files in the Resources folder - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398937/getting-a-list-of-files-in-the-resources-folder-ios)
it works perfectly but only for basic folder and not with .atlas extension

```
  NSString * resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
  NSString * documentsPath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MYATLAS.atlas"];
  NSError * error;
  NSArray * directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsPath error:&error];
```

Comment: Do you want to preload texture, or load and use them right away?

Comment: I want to load them and create SKTextures and add them all in a NSDictionnary and use for the keys the names of the files

Comment: I will adapt my answer to use dictionary

Comment: Btw. I think preloading the atlas would work fine for you, you will be able to grab every texture by name very quickly from preloaded atlas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First init your atlas like this:

```
SKTextureAtlas* myAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"MYATLAS.atlas"];
```

Then you can load all textures into an dictionary

```
NSMutableDictionary* texturesDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for(NSString* textureName in myAtlas.textureNames){
    SKTexture* texture = [myAtlas textureNamed:textureName];
    [texturesDictionary setObject:texture key:textureName];
}
```

or just preload atlas for later use

```
[myAtlas preloadWithCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! i never see before that SKTextureAtlas has textureNames.