# Select File Name created with Date and Time for later use?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdocument

```
 NSString *dateString= [self currentDateandTime];

//create file path and file name

  NSString *docDirectory =
[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *pdfPath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"602_TW0023.%@_pdf.pdf",dateString]];
NSLog(@"Path: %@", pdfPath);
```

i converted an image to pdf and saved it with current date and time.
How can i use this file to upload to ftp or php.

```
NSString* theFileName = [pdfPath lastPathComponent];
```

how to call above string into other method.can we set tag or what? i'm new to programming.
point me right direction.

i tried a lot.

```
NSString *applicationDocumentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filepath =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%@",applicationDocumentsDir, @"%@"];

NSData *uploadData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: filepath];
```

Comment: you can create a singleton or global variable, or you can get the names of all the files in the DocumentsDirectory and sort them by date. [link to question about getting names of files in directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398937/getting-a-list-of-files-in-the-resources-folder-ios)

Comment: thanks for reply.  but i dont need to list. because those files are temporary files.my app handles only one file at a time

Comment: is there any way to select file with it's extension? @IgnacyDebicki

Comment: if you are handling one file at a time, you can always set a property of one of the classes as NSString that contains the filename

Comment: i tried that, seriously but it didn't work for me.i set a property for  file that i'm creating and i tried to retrieve..but i'm missing some logic @IgnacyDebicki

Comment: can you post some code of how you have been trying to pass the filename

Comment: ,i did can u check it out?@IgnacyDebicki,http://stackoverflow.com/q/25396214/3923716,this is also my question same topic, u can see my code here

Comment: also, if you are handling only one file at a time and then delete it, can't you use a static filename like "image.pdf"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your class.h:

```
 @property(strong,nonatomic)NSString *filepath;
```

when you create the file path add:

```
self.filepath=pdfPath;
```

Then, when creating the data to upload use:

```
NSData *uploadData =[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.filepath];
```

this will make sure you have the same file path when saving and reading the pdf