# How to throw the same errors as standard library does, in Swift?

Tags: swift, error-handling, standard-library

Suppose I’m writing a function that reads from a file. This function doesn’t resort to standard library, but I’d like it to behave like the standard library’s when failing, which may mean throwing an exception.

How do I make that exception similar to what the standard libray would have thrown, so that the caller can handle it the same way? Or, if this not desirable, why?

---

It [seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34877027/how-get-the-list-of-errors-thrown-by-a-function) that there is no way of knowing what a specific function can throw, either programmatically or from Apple’s documentation.

Is there a list of standard library exceptions?

Currently, I’m down to defining my own enum error cases:

```
enum FileError: Error {
    case fileNotFound(at path: String)
    case writingToReadOnlyFile(at path: String)
}
```

I find this redundant.