# How to find exceptions thrown by Foundation methods in Swift 3?

Tags: exception, swift3

Is there a way to find what exceptions are thrown by Foundation methods in Swift 3? In particular, I'm using the `FileManager` class to copy a file from the app bundle to the document directory. The `copyItem` method throws an exception if the destination file exists. How to catch that specific exception? The only way I've found is to parse the `localizedDescription`, which is ugly and likely not robust:

```
func copySampleReport() {
    let fileManager = FileManager()
    let reportName = "MyFile.txt"
    if let documentUrl = try? fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false), let reportUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: URL(fileURLWithPath: reportName).deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent, withExtension: URL(fileURLWithPath: reportName).pathExtension) {
        debugPrint("Copying \(reportUrl) to \(documentUrl)")
        do {
            try fileManager.copyItem(at: reportUrl, to: documentUrl.appendingPathComponent(reportName))
            debugPrint("File copied succesfully!")
        }
        catch {
            if error.localizedDescription.range(of:"exists") != nil {
                debugPrint("File exists at destination")
            } else {
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977738/how-to-find-the-kind-of-errors-a-method-may-throw-and-catch-them-in-swift and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34877027/how-get-the-list-of-errors-thrown-by-a-function

Comment: Also, Apple's [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 3.0.1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID10) documentation has an example showing how to use the `CocoaError` struct in Foundation to isolate a specific error. See the section "Catching and Handling an Error".