# how to make a string array from folder files

Tags: swift

Help me please.

There are 2 resource folders and fonts. The second is embedded in the first.
How to scan the fonts folder and get a string array of file names.

thanks.

[image]

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398937/getting-a-list-of-files-in-the-resources-folder-ios

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted so many times. Its purpose is clear and concise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not added the `Fonts` folder as a **folder reference**, but as a folder group like in your screenshot, then all of the fonts will actually appear in your main bundle resource directory as individual files, and *not* in a folder called `Fonts`. However, if you do add it as a folder reference you can access all of your font paths by doing the following:

```swift
 if  let directory = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Fonts", ofType: ""),
     let files = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: directory) {
     for file in files {
         print(file)
     }
 }
```

Fonts added as a *folder reference*

[image: Fonts added as a folder reference]

Fonts added as a *folder group*

[image: Fonts added as a folder group]

Alternatively, and not as elegant, if you wish to keep `Fonts` as a folder group, you could find all of your font files by doing the following instead:

```swift
if  let directory = Bundle.main.resourcePath,
    let files = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: directory) {
    for file in (files.filter { ["ttf", "otf"].contains(($0 as NSString).pathExtension)  }) {
        print(file)
    }
}
```