# Bundle.main.url cannot find file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, bundle

I tried several answers from different posts but none of them solved my problem.

Situation I am in:

- The project is called **XcodeTests** and the only target it has is **XcodeTests**
- I have a `my_file.txt` file at `<ProjectRoot>/XcodeTests/res/`
- Upon creating `my_file.txt`, I made sure that target **XcodeTests** was selected
- Both `res` folder and `my_file.txt` exists in storage directories confirmed by Finder
- In **Build Phase** of XcodeTests, **CopyBundleResources** does include `my_file.txt`

The following code throws `Fatal error: Couldn't find requested file`:

```
import Foundation

guard let myFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "my_file", withExtension: "txt")
else
{
    fatalError("Couldn't find requested file")
}
```

What should I do so that `Bundle.main.url` can find `my_file.txt`?

Comment: Well your file is inside a directory called res. try `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "my_file", withExtension: "txt", subdirectory: "res")`

Comment: I added`, subdirectory: "res"`. It still cannot find `my_file.txt`.

Comment: What color is your subdirectory? I guess it is not blue. It is probably yellow. Possible duplicate of [Swift - How do I get the file path inside a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34548888/2303865)

Comment: It's grey. I think it's the color for group folders.

Comment: check my comment above again

Comment: Just print out the contents of your bundle like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26571579/5318223 and see if the file is there, and if it has parent folder

Comment: @akjndklskver Thanks for that info. I `cd`ed into `Bundle.main.bundlePath` and realized this target is a command line program. Even tho Xcode allows copy resources to bundle and this "bundle" does have a valid address, no resources actually get copied.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out it's because the target itself is a command line program and does not support **Copy Bundle Resources**. Even tho resources can be listed there, none of them will be copied.